# Mysql alter comment column only

Tags: mysql, alter

I'm wondering if it's possible to change only comment on a column in mysql without change the column definition data like name, type and key.

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE `user` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(11) COMMENT 'id of user'
```

Can i change only the comment is this example ?

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [MySQL specification](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html), you must repeat the entire column definition if you want to redefine the comment:

```
ALTER TABLE user MODIFY id INT(11) COMMENT 'id of user';
```